# columnchart using gwt visualization api

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I am new to gwt visualization. I want to create a Column chart using gwt visualization api.
Problem is I am not able to plot values on x-axis. I am not sure how the x and y axis values are plotted. Y axis values are plotted automatically but not for x axis.

```
 Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Create a column chart visualization.
                    ColumnChart colChart = new ColumnChart(createTable(), createOptions());
                    basePanel.add(colChart);
                }
            };
    VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, ColumnChart.PACKAGE);


private Options createOptions() {
        Options options = Options.create();
        options.setWidth(500);
        options.setHeight(400);
        options.set3D(true);
        options.setTitle("Velocity");
        options.setTitleX("Iterations");
        options.setTitleY("Points accepted");

        return options;
    }

    private AbstractDataTable createTable() {

        final DataTable data = DataTable.create();
        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Points");
        data.addRows(3);

        data.setValue(0, 0, 1);
        data.setValue(1, 0, 5);
        data.setValue(2, 0, 9);

        return data;
    }
```

Can anybody tell how these values are plotted and how to achieve this? I am using a gwt visualization 1.0.2.jar.

Comment: You need to add a second column of data.  Your first column is the x-axis values and the second column is the y-axis values.

Comment: I tried that one too, but it adds another vertical bar on x axis.

Comment: Ahh, I think you are loading the wrong chart package.  You need to load the corechart package, not the columnchart package: `VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, CoreChart.PACKAGE);`.  The columnchart package is deprecated.

Comment: I'm using gwt visualization 1.0.2 and it doesn't have CoreChart.PACKAGE

Comment: CoreChart.PACKAGE is available in 1.1.2. Since its maven dependency is not available I used 1.0.2. So I created a dependency locally for 1.1.2. and I see both x and y axis values. @asgallant Thanks for pointing me to a correct package.